# Dynamic attr in textbox data-bind knockout JS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I need to add dynamic attr in textbox data-bind

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="
  attr:{
    name:$data.FieldName, 
    req: !$data.Nullable, 
    placeholder:$data.DefValue, 
    disabled:$data.Editable != null && !$data.Editable == true, 
    required: $data.Nullable != null && !$data.Nullable, 
    'data-bv-notempty':$data['data-bv-notempty'], 
    'data-bv-notempty-message': $data['data-bv-notempty-message']
  }, 
  value: $root.selScreen.isEditMode() ? ActualData : ''
">
```

if I define in array below list then it should add

```
'data-bv-notempty': $data['data-bv-notempty'], 
'data-bv-notempty-message': $data['data-bv-notempty-message']
```

OR

```
'data-bv-notempty':'true', 
'data-bv-notempty-message': 'This field can not be empty'
```

like wise

```
'data-bv-regexp':'true',
'data-bv-regexp-regexp':''^\d*'',
'data-bv-regexp-message': 'This field can only consist of integer value'
```

What ever I add in Array it should be add in this

```
data-bind="attr:{
  'data-bv-regexp':'true',
  'data-bv-regexp-regexp':''^\d*'',
  'data-bv-regexp-message': 'This field can only consist of integer value'
}"
```

Don't want to use jQuery or Observable object

Answer (score 0):

> Don't want to use jQuery or Observable object

You're posting a question with the tags [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js), but you don't want to use jQuery or observables?

My interpretation of your question (correct me if I'm wrong):

> How can one use the `attr` binding using a combination of properties defined in both the *view* and the *viewmodel*?

For example, in your root viewmodel there are some defaults:

```
this.defaultAttributes = {
  'data-bv-notempty':'true'
};
```

And you want to add these defaults in your view, while also keeping the possibility to add specific attributes:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {
    id: 'item-' + $index()
  }">
</div>
```

I'd suggest you use `Object.assign` to merge the two:

```
<div data-bind="attr: Object.assign({
    id: 'item-' + $index()
  }, $root.defaultAttributes)">
</div>
```